# Comparar dos fechas con dos formatos distintos

Tags: java, date

Tengo las siguientes fechas en estos formatos

1. Mon Jul 15 08:49:49 CEST 2019
2. 2019-07-12T10:55:00.000Z

El segundo valor lo recojo de una HashMap de string a Date. Pero al parecer no es un tipo Date. Alguna idea de como podria comparar estos valores

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer es parsear una de las dos fechas para que tengan el mismo formato, ya que de por si no puedes comparar peras con manzanas

Comment: Y como podria parsear este formato? 2019-07-12T10:49:00.000 a un date normal? No estoy logrando hacerlo

Comment: He intentado hacer un getCdate pero no existe. Ya que debugeando me di cuenta de que el campo que sale en la imagen comparte el formato que quiero comparar

Comment: Tienes dos expresiones inspeccionadas, puedes ver de qué clase son las instancias devueltas concatenando `.getClass()` a cada una.

Comment: Si hago un entry.getValue().getClass().Me devuelve un java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para parsear `2019-07-12T10:55:00.000Z` he supuesto que es un string.

```
  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
    Date date = dateFormat.parse("2019-07-12T10:55:00.000Z");// Paso ese string a fecha
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); // Le doy un farmato a esa fecha en este caso dd-MM-yyyy puedes ponerle hora y segundos si quieres ;)
    String dateStr = formatter.format(date); // Ya tengo mi fecha formateada en string
```

El resultado final es : `12-07-2019`

Comment: He probado a hacer lo que me comentaste, pero si en vez de meterle el literal se lo mando como variable. y lo parseo a string. Obtenhgo el siguiente error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date

Comment: Pensaba que `2019-07-12T10:55:00.000Z` era una variable string, yo no tengo nada mas añadido y me funciona correctamente.